# Saving textarea text in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I am trying to save the the text input on a textarea using AngularJS.

I need to save this each time the text is changed and store the values in a service so that I can retrieve it later to submit to the Database.

My textarea in my **form.html** looks as follows:

```
<textarea class="textarea" style="width: 90%; margin-left: 5%" rows="7" maxlength="100" ng-model="newMessage" placeholder="Additional comments"></textarea>

<!-- This isnt displaying anything -->
{{newMessage}}
<!-- This isnt displaying anything -->        
{{myTextArea}}
```

In my controller I implement a $watch() on the ng-model as below, but this is not working. I also tried to implement a ng-change but again with no success.

```
$scope.$watch("newMessage", function (newVal, oldVal) 
{
    console.log("Getting here..."); // Getting here

    if (newVal !== oldVal)
    {
        // This block is never executed
        $scope.myTextArea = "This is new values:  " + newVal;

        // Save the new textarea text to service   
        save($scope.myTextArea);
    }
});

$scope.save = function () 
{
    // This block never executed
    console.log("sharedProperties.setAdditionalCommentsText(): ");
    sharedProperties.setAdditionalCommentsText($scope.myTextArea);

    console.log("sharedProperties.getAdditionalCommentsText: " + sharedProperties.getAdditionalCommentsText());
};
```

And my service for saving the textarea text like below:

```
app.service('sharedProperties', function()
{
    // Initialise the Variables
    var additionalCommentsText = "";  

    return 
    {
        // Get and set the Additional Comments Text
        getAdditionalCommentsText: function()
        {
            return additionalCommentsText;
        },
        setAdditionalCommentsText: function(value)
        {
            additionalCommentsText = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: do you define `$scope.newMessage` in your controller?      it should be `$scope.save($scope.myTextArea)` not `save($scope.myTextArea)` in `$scope.watch`

Comment: No I had it defined but it didn't help either. Read on another SO post to remove it so hence it's not there anymore.

Comment: `$scope.newMessage` should be defined and the function assigned to `$scope.save` should take a param.

Comment: I defined the newMessage and changed the save as well as suggested but still no luck. The problem is that Im actually never even getting to call the save function in that block because the if (newVal !== oldVal) statement doesnt seem to get executed.

Comment: i try it myself and it works, pls check my answer to see if it  help .

Comment: Hi LFJ - apologies. Think it was a problem with my debugger not showing the updated versions when I ran it. If you want to change the comment to an answer Ill mark as correct. Upvoted!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do it in my computer and it works,

in controller:

```
$scope.newMessage = '';  
$scope.$watch('newMessage', function(newValue, oldValue) {   
    if (newValue !== oldValue) {
        console.log('do save staff');
    }
});
```

in html:

```
<textarea class="textarea" style="width: 90%; margin-left: 5%" rows="7" maxlength="100" ng-model="newMessage" placeholder="Additional comments"></textarea>
```

output:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Try This, with `ng-change`

```
<textarea class="textarea" style="width: 90%; margin-left: 5%" rows="7" maxlength="100" ng-model="newMessage" ng-change="save(newMessage);" placeholder="Additional comments"></textarea>
```

JS

```
$scope.save = function (message) {
    console.log(message);
};
```